# making a decorator that can access the arguments of the function that is taking as input in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, decorator

so, i want to write a decorator that takes in a function and based on that function arguments decides wether or not to do something.

the idea is that with this decorator the functions supports an input like this:

```
myFunction("a", "b", "c")
```

and an input like this:

```
myFunction(["a", "b", "c"])


def accept_list_input(function):
   def wrapper(function):
      try:
         function()
      except typeError:
      # (function's argument that i don't know how to access)= function's argument that i don't know how to access[0]

   return wrapper


@accept_list_input
def myFunction(*arguments):
   #stuff
```

Comment: so what exactly don't you want this function to allow as arguments?

Comment: i want this function to take as an input both a list object and unlimited arguments separated with comas but not as a list

Comment: That makes no sense, you just contradicted yourself by saying you want it to take a list but not arguments as a list.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.  What about your current approach doesn't work the way you want it to.  Can you provide an example of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `myFunction(*args, **kwargs)` in the decorator function and write the decorator function like that: `def decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)`

In your case it would by similar to this:

```
myFunction(["a", "b", "c"])


def accept_list_input(function):
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      try:
         function(*args, **kwargs)
      except typeError:
      # (function's argument that i don't know how to access)= function's argument that i don't know how to access[0]

   return wrapper


@accept_list_input
def myFunction():
   #stuff
```

Comment: so, i noticed now that i have formatted my question really badly, i am new to this site... but where do i have to write *args and **kwargs

Comment: i can't understand where i have to put *args and **kwargs

Comment: sorry if i keep commenting, but i really need an example.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i came up till now:

```
def accept_list_input(func, *args, **kwargs):
  def wrapper(func):
    try:
      func(args)
    except TypeError:
      for arg in args:
        if type(arg)== tuple:
          arg= arg[0]
        func(arg)
  return wrapper
```

Comment: what is it that you do not want this function to take as parameters? you need to be more clear in your ask

Answer (score 0):

clearer question:

i'll make another example becuse i know that the question isn't the best one:

```
def add_numbers(*integer_numbers):
    sum= 0
    for integer in integer_numbers:
        sum+= integer
    return sum

# this is not the real method i am struggling on in my project, it's an example
# the function above takes an input formatted like this:
# add_numbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# i want the function to support both add_numbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and add_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])


def accept_list_input(a_function, *args):
    def wrapper(func, args):
        try:
            a_function(args)
        except TypeError:
            for argument in args:
                if type(argument)== tuple:
                    argument= argument[0]
                    break
            a_function(args)
    return wrapper(a_function, args)
```

Comment: the thing is that idk how to access the function's arguments in the decorator: i want to be able to see what type of arguments there are in the function passed as argument in the decorator